# Is there a simple way to use Git as a remote (and main) repository on an NAS?

Tags: git

Say, if I have an NAS (the Western Digital EX2100 Network Attached Storage, or a RAID drive hooked up to a remote iMac), which I can use as a network drive, and is already set to mirror RAID, so the data is safer there, and then I copy a coding exercise folder from my local Macbook Air to this NAS.

Then a few days later, if I copy this folder from the NAS to my Macbook Pro (another Mac), and start doing some changes and commit, is there a simple way to "push" back to the NAS?

I know I can remove that folder from NAS and just copy the new folder from the Macbook Pro to the NAS.  But what if I did a small change (and commit) on the Macbook Pro, and then several small changes (and commits) on the Macbook Air, is there an easy way to "push" back to the NAS's Git folder (and have those commits merged)?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, this is exactly what Git remotes are for. In your example, start by initializing a Git repo at the local exercise folder location:

```
<exercise_folder> $ git init
```

Commit all of your files:

```
<exercise_folder> $ git add -A
<exercise_folder> $ git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Then clone the repo to the NAS location:

```
<NAS_dir_above_where_you_want_repo> $ git clone <exercise_folder>
```

Set up the NAS repo as a remote named "origin" (it's conventional) in the local repo:

```
<exercise_folder> $ git remote add origin <NAS_repo_dir>
```

Now when you make a change to the local repo, you can push that change to the remote location:

```
<exercise_folder> $ git add -A
<exercise_folder> $ git commit -m "<description of the change>"
<exercise_folder> $ git push origin master
```

Note: this is just one way to accomplish what you've asked. As @sendaran points out, there are lots of ways to do it. In any case, you're going to set up a repo at the exercise folder location and another on the NAS and connect them via the "git remote" command.

The commands I've listed above will get you started. When you're ready to learn more, I would start by reading about the .gitignore file and documentation for the "git add" command; "git add -A" works, but is a brute-force solution. Then I'd read about git branches. The commands above assume you're just working on the branch called "master".

And no, you don't need to run a Git server on the NAS to use this method.

Comment: It would perhaps be simpler to setup by creating a bare repository on the NAS with `git init --bare`, clone to local directory `git clone <path/to/nas-repo>`, move the exercise folder to the cloned workspace, commit and push. NAS drive probably won't be used as a workspace. Cloning from local to remote if there isn't an existing repository is slightly counterintuitive.

Comment: I think the question I have is more about "how": do you need to run a Git server on the NAS?  (the NAS is running Linux), but I don't know how to use any command line on the NAS or is it even allowed.  What are the command lines or steps in each of the processes you described, such as "push that change to the remote location"?

Comment: I edited my answer to provide the "how". Let me know if anything's not clear.